# Retrieving a list from POST data in Django

Tags: django, post, dictionary

In Django, what is the way to retrieve a list from the `POST` data

If I send in my ajax call a parameter like `'ids:[1,2,3,4]'`

How should I retrieve it  in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Use [QueryDict.getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method:

```
request.POST.getlist('ids')
```

Answer (score -1):

In your view:

```
request.POST.get('ids', [])
```